# django-allauth: How can I add a Site for my domain?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth

I'm new to Django and I've installed django-allauth.

I followed the docs, but I'm stuck on the Post-Installation steps:

> 1. Add a Site for your domain, matching settings.SITE_ID (django.contrib.sites app).
> 2. For each OAuth based provider, add a Social App (socialaccount app).
> 3. Fill in the site and the OAuth app credentials obtained from the provider.

I don't understand this part at all.

I tried to register the site & socialaccount but nothing changes. Also, I saw that I had to define Site ID so I put this in my settings:

```
SITE_ID = '1'
```

Please, could anybody help me with this? Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I found a tutorial that let me go on with this. I registered an app in facebook and I obtained a APP ID & secret and I established by /admin/socialaccount/socialapp/ but even when all is ready i get

```
      Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    MyIP/accounts/profile/
Using the URLconf defined in gameproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^accounts/ ^ ^signup/$ [name='account_signup']
^accounts/ ^ ^login/$ [name='account_login']
^accounts/ ^ ^logout/$ [name='account_logout']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/change/$ [name='account_change_password']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/set/$ [name='account_set_password']
^accounts/ ^ ^inactive/$ [name='account_inactive']
^accounts/ ^ ^email/$ [name='account_email']
^accounts/ ^ ^confirm-email/$ [name='account_email_verification_sent']
^accounts/ ^ ^confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$ [name='account_confirm_email']
^accounts/ ^ ^confirm_email/(?P<key>\w+)/$
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/$ [name='account_reset_password']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/done/$ [name='account_reset_password_done']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/key/done/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key_done']
^accounts/ ^social/
^accounts/ ^weibo/
^accounts/ ^persona/login/$ [name='persona_login']
^accounts/ ^instagram/
^accounts/ ^openid/login/$ [name='openid_login']
^accounts/ ^openid/callback/$ [name='openid_callback']
^accounts/ ^vimeo/
^accounts/ ^twitter/
^accounts/ ^vk/
^accounts/ ^linkedin/
^accounts/ ^github/
^accounts/ ^google/
^accounts/ ^facebook/
^accounts/ ^facebook/login/token/$ [name='facebook_login_by_token']
^accounts/ ^facebook/channel/$ [name='facebook_channel']
^accounts/ ^angellist/
^accounts/ ^bitly/
^accounts/ ^dropbox/
^accounts/ ^stackexchange/
^accounts/ ^twitch/
^accounts/ ^soundcloud/
The current URL, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

when im trying to check in my website in MYIP/accounts/profile/

Comment: We want to help but there's a way to ask so as to elicit good answers. You have 2 questions. The 1st one is "How to I add a site to my project?" and the 2nd is "How to I make allauth cooperate with Facebook?" These are 2 widely different issues and should be asked as 2 different SO questions. If the 1st question has been solved, then you should delete this question and ask a *new* one. If not, then please edit your question to refocus on the site issue and open a new question for the Facebook issue. Or if you believe there is a substantial relation between the 2 issues, please clarify it.

Comment: I answer my question looking at https://speakerdeck.com/tedtieken/signing-up-and-signing-in-users-in-django-with-django-allauth

Answer (score 11):

1. Add a Site through the admin panel. Since I am developing on my machine, I've set up my site with the "Domain Name" field set as "127.0.0.1:8000" and the "Display Name" shouldn't matter.
2. Your SITE_ID in settings.py needs to match the actual database ID from the Site you added through the admin panel. To do this you can go to the details of the Site you created through the admin panel and look at the url for the ID number. Mine ended up being "5"(I recreated several sites trying to get this to work).
3. Create a Social Application through the admin panel. This is pretty easy as you only need to setup an Application through the provider (e.g. create a Facebook app on Facebooks website) and use the secret code and app ID they give you to fill out the django form. Be sure to add the django Site you created in step 1 to the Social Application you are making in this step.

NOTE: I did this and kept getting a 404. This was due to me being logged in as an admin, thus, the url '/accounts/login' decided I was already logged in and redirected to '/accounts/profile' which didn't exist yet. An easy fix if you run into this is to clear your cookies for your django page and visit '/accounts/login' again.  Post in comments if you need help.

Comment: your "NOTE" saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

check if **django.contrib.site** has been added in the INSTALLED_APPs  section in django settings

Answer (score -2):

**Post-Installation**

In your Django root execute the command below to create your database tables:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Now start your server, visit your admin pages (e.g. `http://localhost:8000/admin/`) and follow these steps:

1. Add a Site for your domain, matching `settings.SITE_ID` (`django.contrib.sites` app).
2. For each `OAuth` based provider, add a `Social App` (socialaccount app).
3. Fill in the site and the `OAuth` app `credentials` obtained from the `provider`.

[image]

Comment: This answer was not helpful.  I will post back when I figure it out; I too am having trouble understanding what needs to be done after installation.